# connecting android to pc via usb cabe and file transfer

Tags: usb-connection-mode

So I can connect my android tab to the pc and I can enter the MTP mode yet when I try to transfer files it loads for ages then refuse to move any file to pc or from pc to phone.
The same cable works well with other android without any hustle and fast.
I tried to go to device manager (win 7) and update the android driver but Windows said I have the best.
PLS HELP!
Thanks in advance. 
Gihon

Comment: What tablet is it?

Comment: Tecno DroIpad H8

Comment: (Sorry for the late answer, I didn't see your post before.)

Answer (score 0):

Some device is not working as usual. So you have to enable developer option from your mobile setting.

Developer option comes in different location in different mobile

like

may be show in setting

or

may be in setting >> additional setting

If developer option is not shown in your mobile then you have to follow some step for showing developer option in setting.

Go to Settings > About phone > Tap 5 to 6 times on Build number
now your developer option will show in setting or other relative position.
and then enable your developer option as well as enable usb debugging.

and then try with your cable

hope this will work for you

Comment: How do developer options speed up MTP transfer? Never heard of that.

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed the answer. (I almost gave up...)
So, yes, I did this before I have the developer mode also the debugging mode and it is still the same.